# Four groups, sixteen words

Tags: word-property, connect-wall

These 16 words can be separated into 4 categories... What are they? All of them have something in common... What is it?

Bean, Iron, Bird, Notorious, Cannonball, Ripper, Prince, Zodiac, Clown, Slim, Sam, Dr, Dizzy, Fifty, Sugar, Brown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overall connection is

> Pseudonyms/nicknames

As a starting point, one potential group seems to be

> Serial killers: Zodiac (Killer), (Son of) Sam, (Jack the) Ripper, (Killer) Clown (John Wayne Gacy)

Another group is formed by:

> Rappers: Fifty (Cent), Slim (Shady), Notorious (B.I.G), Dr (Dre)

Then there's

> (Charlie) Bird (Parker), Dizzy (Gillespie) and presumably two other jazz musicians. Bean (Coleman Hawkins) and Cannonball (Julian Adderley) must be the other two as they're the remaining words.

The fourth category might be

> Boxers: Sugar (Ray Leonard), Iron (Mike Tyson), Prince (Naseem Hamid), Brown (Bomber) (Joe Louis)

Note on solving:

> Zodiac, Ripper and Sam jumped out as serial killer names; Notorious pointed towards rappers and Slim and Fifty obviously went there; Dizzy and then Bird gave the jazz group; and Sugar pointed towards the boxers. Though I did have Dr in the serial killers initially, and Prince in with singers. And pretty much any word looks like it could a jazz nickname based on the list on Wikipedia.

Comment: Very good just needs a little touch up

Comment: rot13(Zvffvat enccre zvtug or Qe Qer)

Comment: Please don't write answers in the comments

Comment: Hi @Jaques - on PSE if someone is close to the final answer it's fine for other users to provide their own observations as comments to help push them over the line and complete their solution (in fact it's actively encouraged, to avoid lots of one-line partial answers). Obviously if it will spoil the puzzle it's best to use [rot13](https://rot13.com/) to hide them from a casually passing eye. (Equally obviously, since I don't know the history of the comment edits here I'm trying to provide catch-all advice in this comment mainly for the benefit of others who may read this...) Happy Puzzling :)

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Did you find it easy?

Comment: Only after I got lucky and recognised two of the categories fairly quickly, plus those particular two were enough to point me towards the likely overall common link. Without that I would have struggled. I think without Zodiac, Ripper, and Notorious it would have been a lot harder. But I think these always boil down to what clicks with someone and on another day I mightn't have made those initial connections